# How to run a Blender add-on function to export an object using script

Tags: python, scripting, export

I am working on a project that involves generating many objects in Blender using a python script. The number of generated files can be somewhere between 500 to 5000. I need to export each of these objects as an IGES file.

I found this awesome add-on to export IGES files from Blender. [ExportIGES](https://dsculptor.gumroad.com/l/exportiges?layout=profile)

However, since there are a lot of objects, it would be great if I could perform this exporting process using a script to automate the process.

Do you know how we can run this add-on using a Blender python script?

Comment: Isn't that add-on able to batch output your objects separated already?
https://dsculptor.gumroad.com/l/exportiges?layout=profile#:~:text=value%20is%202.-,Batch%20Mode,-%3A%20Saves%20objects%20as

Comment: Yes. It can. But the problem is that some of the objects have intersections and this make it impossible for the add-on to export all objects, but for each single object, it won’t have any problem.

Comment: why don't you write a very small "dumb" script, which just moves all objects to a big grid so nothing intersects, then use the add-on? this could even be done with geometry nodes or instancing.

Comment: That's a good idea. Thanks!
However, I need to recover their original location in another CAD software, which can take a lot to be done considering the high number of objects. 
I am now doing this manually, but it is still very important to do this using a script.